# Add a combo box to a DbGrid in delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to add a combo box to a Dbgrid in Delphi. i used Nxquery as data set.
Is there any way to do that without drawing cell?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As was indicated in an answer subsequently deleted, each Column of a DBGrid has a Picklist which behaves like an embedded combobox.  It has an Items sub-property which you can populate in the Object Inspector or in code.

Comment: See [Defining a Lookup List Column](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Defining_a_Lookup_List_Column) in the Delphi documentation. The link is to current docs (for Berlin), but the capability to do this goes back to Delphi 1, IIRC.